# How to open "Preferred Language" Page in iOS Settings App programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, settings

I am working on localizing my app, and wanted to implement a feature where a user selects button (or a tableView cell in my case), and it should open up not just the settings page, but into the "Preferred Language" page like this

[image]

I have
`UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)` inside of my didSelect method but thats just for the base settings page.
Is there any way to just open the language page from the start?

Comment: Unfortunately you can only open your apps main settings page

Comment: @Paulw11 thats a bummer :(, but thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to open inside of ***Preferred Languages***.

You can open the app settings page as your screenshot image.
***openSettingsURLString*** is the url for it.

```
if let url: URL = .init(string; UIApplication.openSettingsURLString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```